# How to print the expression instead of value?

Tags: python, variables, expression

I am trying to print the conditions that I have given in text format instead of printing the final value of conditions. Below is the sample code for better explanation.

```
a = 5
b = 10
condition = a>b and a+b<10
if condition:
    print"successful"
else:
    print"unsuccessful"
print("The conditions applied was",condition)
```

Here I want the system to print `"a>b and a+b<10"` but it prints `"False"` because the final value of condition is `False`

Comment: simpliest way would be to create a mapping between the condition and the value, e.g. `{'a>b and a+b<10': a>b and a+b<10}`

Comment: it's possible to `eval()` the string (but is unsafe if you're user accepting input) or build a proper parser

Comment: I have to use the condition at multiple places and I don't want to write the whole condition again and again at different if-else statements, so I save the expression in a variable "condition" to use the term "condition" directly whereever I need it and since with every condition I get different results, I want to save the results/output with the conditions ( "a>b and a+b<10") so that I can see later whcih conditions gave what results.
So in the above example how shall I do this? 
Is there anyway to print it later and use a simple short variable instead of writing the whole condition again

Comment: It depends on your use case and Python level, but I believe this is the most elegant way I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you can, but I do **NOT** recommend it,
to store the condition in string form (for the printing part), then use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) when actually need the value. like this:

```py
a = 5
b = 10
condition = 'a>b and a+b<10'
if eval(condition):
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccessful")
print("The conditions applied was",condition)
```

Output:

```
unsuccessful
The conditions applied was a>b and a+b<10
```

**AGAIN: USING EVAL IS A BAD AND DANGEROUS PROGRAMMING PRACTICE** (some explanation why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), and in many other places around the web)

Comment: Why are you writing an answer advising them what *not* too do?

Comment: Incidentally it has become very fashionable on SO to call 'eval()' bad under all circumstances, but it does have legitimate use cases

Comment: @Chris_Rands well, because in a simple enough script where you control the conditions it might be the simplest solution, avoiding the duplication of a safer solution... if that's what OP needs, he can choose to use it, but I won't be comfortable just leaving the answer without any disclaimer

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it worked for me perfectly. I am not taking any user input btw.
Thanks both of you for quick response.

Comment: when doing data science work there is very little danger in using eval.

Answer (score 0):

Since you updated your question in the comments, saying

> I want to save the results/output with the conditions ( "a>b and a+b<10") so that I can see later whcih conditions gave what results.

I think you should use a lambda and the inspect module.

```
a = 5
b = 10
condition = lambda x, y: (x+y) > 10

if condition(a, b):
    print('condition passed !')
else:
    print('condition failed !')
```

And if you want to print the condition, you could see it doing...

```
from inspect import getsourcelines

print("The condition was...")
print(getsourcelines(condition)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks IMCoins, this worked as well. I got the solution.

Comment: A reasonable idea, although not full proof (e.g. fails in the Python interpreter). Also no reason to use `lambda` here, a regular `def` function is preferable when assigning the function to a name